# Round robin scroll of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, round-robin

Consider the following arrangement ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZRSZ/)):

```
         <------- Full width occupied ------->
---------------------------------------------------------
| Div A | Div B | Div C | Div D | Div E | Div F | Div G | .... H, I, J
---------------------------------------------------------

/* There are Div H, I & J currently not visible */

Button: Left Scroll 
Button: Right Scroll
```

If user presses, Left Scroll - Div H, I & J enter the display area in a sequence, but after J instead of the Div moving deeper towards the left, the it should cycle back to A then B and so on.

I have been able to achieve the motion (see fiddle) but unable to make it Round-Robin.

Comment: You are trying to call this effect round-robin, but a more appropriate name is carousel.  This link might help you: http://www.my-html-codes.com/easy-jquery-carousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is that you are moving the container instead of its children. In order to achieve a carousel the children will have to be shuffled while off screen to their appropriate location in the queue.

I have modified your jsfiddle with an example solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/HZRSZ/4/

The javascript would look something like this:

```
$('#scroll-left').click(function() {
    $('.inner').first()  //select the first child

        //animate its movement left by using the left margin
        .animate({'margin-left':'-=100px'}, function() {

            //then once the item is off screen move it to the other side
            //of the list and reset its margin
            $(this).appendTo('.wrapper').css('margin-left', '');
        });
});
```

and the movement to the right is the same as left just reversed

```
$('#scroll-right').click(function() {
    $('.inner').last()
        .css('margin-left', '-=100')
        .prependTo('.wrapper')
        .animate({'margin-left':'+=100'});
});
```

​

Comment: I was just in the process of starting to write this one up.  You saved me some time.  Good clean solution.